# How to overlay map onto a corner of an image, using that image's GPS exif data?

Tags: gps

I have several hundred JPG images taken during a time lapse of a drive, with each image containing embedded GPS information.

Is there an OS X friendly workflow that can allow me to:

1. create a highway map image (say a 300x300 pixel Google map representing approx a 3mi x 3mi area) centered around the geo coordinates taken from the embedded GPS exif data of that image
2. overlay that map image onto the corner of the original image, and
3. repeat for all images in the time lapse sequence.

I think with a combination of ImageMagick and shell scripting, I can probably do (2) and (3), but I don't know how to do (1).

Comment: With this: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Develop/Frameworks

Comment: I just have to say that this is a super cool idea.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very high-level overview of how I think this could be accomplished with Python:

1. Use a library such as [exif.py](http://sourceforge.net/projects/exif-py/) to parse out the locational data for the photo from the headers
2. Use [mapnik](http://mapnik.org/) to [generate the map](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/GettingStartedInPython) and plot the point location you acquired in the above step
3. Use [pil](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to [resize](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) the png you get output from mapnik and to [place it](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/362879-watermark-with-pil/) onto the corner of the photo